# Outlook AddIn - determine whether an appointment item has been sent or not

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in, appointment

I have an Outlook 2010 C# AddIn, where I have the problem to find out whether an AppointmentItem has already been sent or not.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the following named property is set to true using AppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty

{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}, 0x8229, PT_BOOLEAN

The DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8229000B`

Comment: How exactly should this be used? Could you please give a code example? I cannot find any useful documentation which describes how to use it.

Comment: bool wasSent = AppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8229000B")

Comment: Thank you very much, I will test it soon and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer simply because @Dmitry's comment was missing a "/" as a result of the Comment's section's apparent limitation to handle the syntax completely -

```
bool wasSent = AppointmentItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8229000B");
```

This answer helped me as well!